# unable to authorize with passpost-jwt in expressJs while using angular 7

Tags: node.js, angular, express, jwt, passport.js

I am new in mean stack, using passport-jwt for authorization. I have enabled `cors` for get/post request from outside. so i am able to post/get data using angular 7, but unable to authorize token generated by JWT. One thing, authorization is working fine while using RestClient Addon on firefox(similar to postman in chrome) which you see in this image [image: Restclient].

But while trying to get request from same api using angular then getting this [image: consoleError]
this is my angular service

```
  getProfile():Observable<any>{
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('mean_token'));
    headers.append('Authorization', localStorage.getItem('mean_token'));
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8888/users/profile', {headers:headers});
  }
```

and this is node-express code

```
//profile
router.get('/profile', passport.authenticate('jwt', {session:false}), (req, res, next)=>{
    console.log("profle called");
    res.json({user:req.user});
});
```

struggling for long to find answer, please help me out.

note: rest other APIs for get/post are working find with angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is solution I find for new version of angular (>6) . 
`headers.append()` is not working, since `HttpHeaders` object is immutable.
you need to change your headers to this:

```
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
'Authorization': localStorage.getItem('mean_token') });
```

and now everything is working fine..